# How to include submitted_date and submitted_by in a feedback form in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a feedback form in my app. A user must be logged in to submit a feedback. A user is asked to enter feedback into the text-area. Upon submission, I want to store the user-details in submitted_by field and time of creation of the form as submitted_date (which also contains time).

I have read many discussions regarding the use of `auto-now_add=True` and `auto_now` but there are many opinions about this topic and a little confusing too.

I am using model-form to input data from the user. This is how my different file looks like:

```
# myapp/models.py

class Feedback(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_date = models.DateTimeField() # what do add here in arguments ?

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content + " @ " + self.submitted_date

# myapp/forms.py

class FeedbackForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        fields = [ 'content' ]

# myapp/views.py
def addfeeback(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FeedbackForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # Do I need to do something here ?
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = FeedbackForm()
    return render(request, 'myapp/addFeedback.html', { 'form': form})

 # myapp/urls.py

 url(r'^feedback/$', core_views.addfeeback , name='add-feedback'),

 # myapp/templates/addFeedback.html

 {% extends 'registration/base.html' %}

 {% block title %} Feedback {% endblock %}

 {% block content %}
   <form method="post" >
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
 {% endblock %}
```

It will be highly appreciated if you can suggest relevant changes into my code to do as intended. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using `auto_now_add`. But since you have to set the submitter as well as the date, you wouldn't be gaining much by doing so.

The pattern though is to use `commit=False` when saving the form, then modifying the object that is returned before saving it manually.

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.submitted_by = request.user
    obj.submitted_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    obj.save()
    return redirect('home')
```

Comment: Or `django.utils.timezone.now()`, ideally ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.submitted_by = request.user
    obj.save()
```

In models

```
submitted_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```